# Master Slave replication using WAL: Postgres uuid_generate_v4() to generate primary key

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, wal

I'm creating a users table in postgres with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    uuid character uuid COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    first_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",

    CONSTRAINT agents_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
)
```

`uuid` is primary key of type `uuid`. I'm using `uuid_generate_v4()` to generate uuid values.

I'm not using Postgres in replication mode now.
But later, when I start using replication (most probably WAL streaming replication), will this lead to issues when I add replicas?
Is this similar to using non - deterministic functions (time now()) case?

Can the uuid values differ between master and replica for the same user (not sure if uuid is written to WAL, my assumption is it shouldn't be written)?

Also how are auto increment keys kept in sync across master - slave, is it kept in sync by replaying / inserting rows in the same order as master?

Answer (score 1):

Either you misunderstand streaming replication, or I misunderstand what you are trying to do.

A streaming replication standby is a physical copy of the primary, and if `hot_standby = on`, you can establish *read-only* connections.

The contents of the table will always be identical on both servers, and you won't be able to insert a row on the standby, so it does not matter if the function in the `DEFAULT` clause is deterministic or not.

It seems like you might be looking for something called “multi-master replication”, so that you can modify data on both servers. PostgreSQL doesn't offer a solution for that out of the box.

It seems like you understand some of the problems with multi-master replication, since you ask this question. In most cases, it is better to choose a different architecture that comes with fewer problems.

Comment: I don't want to use multi-master replication. I was wondering since I'm using postgres's generate_uuid_v4() to generate uuid's how will postgres ensure it has the same value on slave node also.
Will the users table on slave node also have `uuid character uuid COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()` in the schema definition or pick value from master node?

Comment: Yes, it will be 100% identical. Database metadata are replicated just like everything else.